# Angular 2 dynamically change contenteditable

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I understand that I can create directives to manipulate attributes. I was wondering if the concept is the same for manipulating the true/false value for contenteditable? or is there a better way? Basically I have comments section that puts comments into a table and I want to be able to edit each comment via a button to activate contenteditable to equal true. I attempted calling a function right out of contenteditable like so `contenteditable="Edited()"` but passing a function doesnt seem to be supported.

**Edit**

I have also attempted to just call contendeditable as a directive like so...

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({ selector: '[myEdit]' })
export class EditDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
       el.nativeElement.contenteditable = 'true';
    }
}
```

then call the directive on the html `<td myedit>`but had no luck. To verify that my directive was called correctly I changed it to change the color of the text and it worked so I am leaning toward this is not the correct way to manipulate the contenteditable attribute.

Also here is plunkr to my attempt https://plnkr.co/edit/029WpB11IqkvYlQieT6h?p=preview

Comment: `contentEditable` is case-sensitive

Comment: you sir are legendary. That solved the problem. Feel free to leave an answer and I would gladly accept it! wonder why it isn't in the actual html.... kinda confusing lol anyways thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `contentEditable` property is a  case-sensitive

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/BkVxEFo4x6j3Y1BS2DWy?p=preview)**

See also

- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_contenteditable.asp